# Convert filename including a scientific number to a file with a decimal number

Tags: linux, decimal, filenames

I have several hundred files like

xyz_1.000e+00.png or xyz_2.300e-01.png or xyz_2.400e+02.png.

I want to convert the filenames so they have the corresponding decimal number at the end

xyz_0001.000.png or xyz_0000.230.png or xyz_0240.000.png

I found some ideas with printf or rename but was not able to put this together so it works. At the end I want to use convert from imagemagick to create a gif of mpg that shows the pictures in the correct order.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop over the files. Use parameter expansion to extract the number, use `printf` to change its format.

```sh
#! /bin/bash
for f in xyz_*.png ; do
    n=${f%.png}  # Remove the extension.
    n=${n#*_}    # Remove the prefix.
    n=$(printf %08.3f "$n")

    prefix=${f%_*}_
    
    new="$prefix$n.png"
    if [[ -e $new ]] ; then
        echo "$new" already exsists, cannot rename "$f". >&2
    fi
    mv "$f" "$new"
done
```

Comment: Thank you.  That does it. But unfortunately my real filename is a little bit more complicated. Sth like abc_def_gh_1.000e00.png. The ${n#*_} removes only a part of the prefix. But fortunately I was able to modify this by my own using now n=$[n#*image_}. Now it works!!! Thank you again.

Comment: @xamo: Note also that `${n##*_}` (doubling the octothorpe) removes as much as possible.